# select siblings with specific class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="chooser" style="display:none;"><div data-id="day">Day <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div data-id="nightamst">Night A <i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div><div data-id="nightzoet">Night Z<i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></div>
<div class="bdownload day" style="display: none;">content</div>
<div class="bdownload nightamst" style="display: none;">content</div>
<div class="bdownload nightzoet" style="display: none;">content</div>
```

Now have the following Javascript:

I want to display the bdownload div with the data id from the previous chooser div.

```
jQuery(".chooser div").click(function(){
        console.log("test");

        jQuery(".chooser").hide();
        jQuery(this).parent(".chooser").siblings(jQuery(this).attr("data-id")).toggle();
    });
```

But when I use this code it gets not toggled. When I put ".bdownload" into the siblings selector, all the bdownloads get toggled, so the fault is in the attr selector. Do I add " to the selector?

Comment: `data-id` doesn't have '.' or '#' in it for the siblings to know if it is matching against a class or id.

Comment: So how do I add the . becasuse it's a class..

Comment: Either put it in the data field itself, or just prepend '.' to the variable in your siblings part

Comment: `.siblings('.' + jQuery(this).attr("data-id"))`

Comment: Thanks @SamBattat that works. I will use the below answer as the answer, but I like the direct approach, so I used yours. Thanks Sam!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.chooser div').click(function() {
  var selector = '.' + $(this).data('id')
  $('.chooser').hide()
  $(this).parent().siblings(selector).toggle()
})
```